# Rails isn't using my `foreign_key` in a belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, `AssetEvent` and `Subsystem`, and a join model between them `AssetEventSubsystem`.  They look like this:

```
RehabEvent < AssetEvent
  has_many :asset_event_subsystems
  has_many :subsystems, :through => :asset_event_subsystems

AssetEventSubsystem
  belongs_to  :rehab_event, :class_name => 'AssetEvent', :foreign_key => "asset_event_id"
  belongs_to  :subsystem

Subsystem
  belongs_to :asset_type
```

When I try to run `RehabEvent.new.asset_event_subsystems.build`, I get back a `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: rehab_event_id`, which is confusing, because I thought that should have been taken care of by the `foreign_key` option in the join model.

**How do I make rails use the column in my database (`asset_event_id`) instead of the default?**

Comment: You need to mention foreign key in both the classes.

Comment: at final u need RehavEvent has_many Subsystem and Subsystem has_many RehavEvent  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `foreign_key` on your `has_many` association as well as your `belongs_to`:

```
has_many :asset_event_subsystems, foreign_key: 'asset_event_id'
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like u need that: ?

```
RehabEvent < AssetEvent
  has_many :asset_event_subsystems
  has_many :subsystems, :through => :asset_event_subsystems, 
           :foreign_key => "asset_event_id"

AssetEventSubsystem
  belongs_to  :rehab_event, :class_name => 'AssetEvent', :foreign_key => "asset_event_id"
  belongs_to  :subsystem

Subsystem
  has_many :asset_event_subsystems
  has_many :rehab_events, :through => :asset_event_subsystems
  belongs_to :asset_type
```

And btw, i dont know your project, but can you use just has_and_belongs_to_many ?

Comment: No, I can't use HABTM- I have to manipulate the join model independently